# saving state of prgoress bar after leaving the activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, progress-bar, onresume

I'm trying to make a progress bar where i can increase/reset the value and i did that so far, but i want to be able to somehow save the state of where I left off after I leave the application,  I need the progress bar's percentage to stay the same even when i quit it, I've read something about on resume methods and shared preferences but I don't really get how to do it and apply it on my own code, any help will be really appreciated, this is my activity's code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import me.itangqi.waveloadingview.WaveLoadingView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WaveLoadingView waveLoadingView;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    Button increase,restart;
    private int prog = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        seekBar=findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        waveLoadingView=findViewById(R.id.waveloading);
        waveLoadingView.setProgressValue(0);
        increase=findViewById(R.id.increase);

        restart=findViewById(R.id.restart);
        increase.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(prog<=100){
                prog+=10;
                updateProgressBar();
            }
            if(prog<50){
                waveLoadingView.setBottomTitle(String.format("%d%%",prog)+"you're drinking too little");
                waveLoadingView.setCenterTitle("");
                waveLoadingView.setTopTitle("");
            }else if(prog<80){
                waveLoadingView.setBottomTitle("");
                waveLoadingView.setCenterTitle(String.format("%d%%",prog)+"You Are Almost There!");
                waveLoadingView.setTopTitle("");
            }else{
                waveLoadingView.setBottomTitle("");
                waveLoadingView.setCenterTitle("");
                waveLoadingView.setTopTitle(String.format("%d%%",prog)+"\r\n You've Made It!");
            }
            if(prog==110){
                waveLoadingView.setProgressValue(0);
            }
        });

        restart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                waveLoadingView.setProgressValue(0);
                waveLoadingView.setBottomTitle("");
                waveLoadingView.setCenterTitle("");
                waveLoadingView.setTopTitle("");
                prog=0;

            }
        });


    }

    private void updateProgressBar() {
        waveLoadingView.setProgressValue(prog);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the shared preferences file to save the value and you can read it when you reopen the app.

private void updateProgressBar() {
waveLoadingView.setProgressValue(prog);
getSharedPreferences("nameyourfile" , MODE_PRIVATE). edit(). putInt("progress', prog). apply() ;
}

OnResume
int prog =  getSharedPreferences("nameyourfile" , MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("progress', yourdefaultvalueprogress) ;
updateProgressBar(prog) ;